# Blank activity or fragment on reopening app after closing by pressing back button

Tags: android, minimize

My app get minimized when I press the back button on the home fragment, which is fine, but when I open it back up it shows me a blank activity. I guess it's not loading the fragment that it's supposed to load.

I added a text view with some text on the activity but it's not showing me that so I'm seeing something else.

How should I manage this issue?

Comment: Show us a code example that reproduces the problem in the smallest steps.

Comment: Your activity has a lifecycle. If a lifecycle state is changing, then a method will be called. If you open your app, after you minimize your application, then the method "onResume()" will be called. Try to use this method in your activity to check, whether your activity is the right activity.

Comment: @SeanStayn, Ok, I solved it. I used toasts and found that the app was returning to the launcher activity, but it was not going through the onCreate so it appeared blank, I now call finish() on the onboarding activity and so far it's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: I'm happy, that I could help you. Can you please vote up my comment?

Comment: @SeanStayn I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: I have created an answer. You can mark them as accepted answer with the hook under the vote arrows. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity has a lifecycle. If a lifecycle state is changing, then a method will be called. If you open your app, after you minimize your application, then the method "onResume()" will be called. Try to use this method in your activity to check, whether your activity is the right activity.

UPDATE(Thanks to Santiago Gil):

It's necessary to call finish() on the onboarding activity.

Answer (score 1):

I used toasts and found that the app was returning to the launcher activity, but it was not going through the onCreate so it appeared blank, I now call finish() on the onboarding activity and so far it's working fine. Thanks